# Laravel stream output doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, laravel, stream

In laravel 10, code like this:

```
// PHP
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

    public function stream()
    {
        $response = new StreamedResponse(function() {
            for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
                $json = ['code' => $i];
                echo json_encode($json) . "\n\n";
                ob_flush();
                flush();
            }
        });

        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
        $response->headers->set('X-Accel-Buffering', 'no');
        $response->headers->set('Cach-Control', 'no-cache');
        return $response;
    }
```

```
// js

        fetch('/test/stream', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')['content']
            },
        })
        .then(response => {
            const stream = response.body;
            const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
            const reader = stream.getReader();

            return reader.read().then(function processText({ done, value }) {
                if (done) {
                    return;
                }
                // console.log(value)
                const json = decoder.decode(value);
                console.log(json)
                
                return reader.read().then(processText);
            })
        })
```

From `console.log(json)`, I can see that it output multiple json strings in one loop and the number is not constant.
But in PHP, I `flush()` string in every loop, it should output one json string immediately, right?

[image]